# just installed 2 gigs of ram but its not showing in system information

Tags: windows-7, memory

I just installed 2 more 1 gig ram cards into my computer, before there was only 2 installed, now there are 4.

I just booted up the computer and got no errors or anything, but when i right click on "my computer" and go to "properties", under "installed memory" it still only shows 2 gigs.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I should mention that I pushed the cards in all the way but the little white snaps did not snap to the sides of the memory cards...however they do not come out easily when I pull on them and I pushed them as far in as they could go.

Comment: If they did not snap in, then the sticks may not be completely inserted. Believe me, I have had times when I was certain it was in, but then I jiggled it and pressed a little harder (assuming it was in the right way in the first place), and it snapped it correctly. Get a light and take a *close* at the RAM sticks; I suspect that you will see that there is a little space between the [notch in the stick and the bump in the slot](http://www.pcdoctor-guide.com/wordpress/images/ram-bank-notch.jpg) (there shouldn’t be, at least not more than about 0.25 mm; it should fit snugly).

Comment: Did you accidently install the memory backwards? It happens and will look like it's snapped in correctly, but the tabs won't come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. **Bios Error**

   That would be the easiest to correct, simply restart your computer, and there is a possibility that your BIOS didn't saw the added RAM the first time. Those thing aren't good and can possibly make mistakes.
2. **Mechanical Error**

   Try removing the RAM and putting it back... Try switching the position in the slots - just   make sure both sticks run correctly with your computer and that your motherboard can deal with the new RAM you installed.

---

*From here on, either you solved your problem or you still have the problem:*

Case 1: **When you switched slots, you started the computer to be welcomed with an error telling you have no more RAM**

This mean that the RAM stick you brought doesn't fit your computer/motherboard *or* that the RAM is DOA. If you know for sure you have correct RAM, DoA (Death on Arival) seems to be your case, It happens to the best ;)

Easiest fix: *try to get a refund (if DoA, it will be easy), find your motherboard manual and get correct RAM for it*.

Case 2: **When you switched RAM, you still had only 2Gig on your computer**

That means that you probably have a problem with one of the RAM slots on you Computer... Or, you motherboard can't deal 4Gig of RAM (which is possible).

"Easy" fix: *get a new motherboard? If you have more than 2 RAM slots, try them out... or deal with 2Gig?*

If you have other results, comment, I'll do my best to answer. And before buying that new motherboard (if you get there), try going somewhere and getting a second opinion, it never killed anyone and can save you money and time, as finding a new motherboard for a already existing computer is a pain.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your new RAM is not installed.

When you install your RAM, here are some things you need to watch out for:

- The RAM has a notch on the bottom that must line up with the notch in the socket. If it doesn't line up, the RAM is not secure in the socket.
- The snaps on the sides must snap into the RAM stick. If you have got the RAM lined up, then when you push it into the socket, the snaps should automatically snap closed (on older computers, you will have to push them into place yourself).

If you miss either of these, then the RAM is not making a good connection with the socket and won't be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check up at your motherboard manual what kind of memory modules does it support. Some motherboards have limitations about how many memory chips it supports on each side of the module.

Try to test each memory module one by one.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Today I just finished installing a 512 megabyte RAM stick.

First I pulled back the empty ram slot's pockets (2 things that holds the ram stick in place) and then I inserted the RAM stick and closed the two pockets. I closed my Desktop up, connected my power adapter, and booted up my computer.

The first thing you should see if you running Windows is a black screen that tells you changes had been made to your system. It will tell you to press <kbd>F1</kbd> to save changes. I pressed <kbd>F1</kbd> and the computer booted up regularly. Then I went into systems property and the changes were there.

In your situation I suggest that you restart your computer without the RAM you added and put it back in like I did and hopefully it will work. I hope this was helpful. Also, go check videos on YouTube about ram installation.